# QLineEdit/QLabel won't stay enabled when saving .ui

Tags: properties, qt-creator, qwidget

I have built a .ui-file in Qt Creator that includes a few different stacked containers: a Tool Box that contains QWidgets with QLabels, QLineEdits etc. in various tabs. A few of the widgets are disabled in the beginning and should only be enabled open some other action. To be able to do that by simply calling widget.setEnabled(True) all the items on the widget, that should appear enabled now, must be enabled in QT Creator, is that correct?

My problem is, that a few items on the QWidget do not stay enabled. I can check their properties checkbox for "enabled", but as soon as I navigate to a different tab in the Tool Box and then return to my QWidget, these two items are disabled again. It also doesn't save their status as enabled when I save the file.
What distinguishes the items that do stay enabled from the ones that don't is that for the ones that don't, in the properties editor, the properties "enabled" and "cursor" appear bold, whereas for the others they don't. All other properties appear to be similar and all items are children of the same QWidget.

I tried replacing them with copied versions of another similar item on the same tab, but that doesn't help.

Comment: I think you might got the problem with moc files. Some times they may do the things like this(I got some situations so). Try to reproduce them, and better reproduce the project file(.pro) . This may clean up the mess. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: If this is still a problem, can you paste/give us a link to your .UI files?

Comment: @waddlesplash: it is not a problem at this point. after neglecting the issue for a while, I couldn't recreate the scenario anymore. Thanks.